# Gnome3 on Xubuntu keeps forgetting my screen resolution

Tags: gnome, xubuntu, resolution

I installed Gnome3 on Xubuntu. After I install I used the display manager to set the resolution at 1024*768. But after every reboot Gnome keeps going to 800*600.

Fixes I tried.

1. I made an executable script with `Xrandr` command to set the resolution right and added it to start up applications. Well at start it seems like it tries to re-size the display but then the screen goes grey for a minute and `Gnome3` loads with 800*600
2. Generated a **xorg.conf** file and tried editing it and no avail.
3. Added the previous script to `lightdm.conf` to run it but still no avail.

Surprisingly XFCE works fine and remembers my resolutions.

FYI I have no NVIDIA or ATI graphics card. I have an integrated Intel G41 chipset with the graphic card.